# Restricting checkout of git branches (VS2017)

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I'm looking for a way to restrict who can checkout branches (IE, switch between them) on Visual Studio. Couldn't find a straight answer on google.

Let's say there are branches A,B, and C on a TFS Repo- I want to set it so only specific users can switch between the various branches, or maybe require a password to do so.

Anybody know a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is not possible.

When you clone a Git Repository you receive the full repo and all of its history. All the commits are in there and any user can checkout the repository at any of the commits. This is an essential part of Git.

If you want parts of a solution to be shielded from certain users, you'll need to put those in a separate repository.

Comment: There is even no way to make this check advisory: there is no pre-checkout / pre-switch hook in Git. If there was, you would be able to at least prevent accidental switch to forbidden branch. What you can do with git hooks is to prevent updates to forbidden branch (push to forbidden branch). That's how roughly protected branches in GitHub, Gitlab etc work.

Comment: Protecting branches on the server for accidental pushes is easy in Azure DevOps through Branch Policies. But there is no way to prevent checking them out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops